# Is there any way to pass index to a nested form partial in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is there any way to pass `index` to activeadmin's nested form partial? The code I have:

```
<% variant.has_many :variant_currencies, allow_destroy: true, heading: false, new_record: 'Add new price modifier' do |variant_currency| %>
  <% variant_currency.template.render partial: 'variant-currency-form', locals: { variant_currency: variant_currency, index: '??? how to pass it here ???' } %>
<% end %>
```

Normally, if I have an iteration, I pass `index` like this:
`<% Post.each_with_index do |post, index| %>`, but how can I tell activeadmin, that I want to have `index` in that `has_many` statement? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with an old fashioned counter...

```
<% counter = 0 %>
<% variant.has_many :variant_currencies, allow_destroy: true, heading: false, new_record: 'Add new price modifier' do |variant_currency| %>
  <% variant_currency.template.render partial: 'variant-currency-form', locals: { variant_currency: variant_currency, index: counter.to_s } %>
  <% counter += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for a hint!